# Tell sage where to find libjpeg

Tags: python, jpeg, python-imaging-library, sage

I have installed [Sage](http://sagemath.org) on Mac OS X. It looks like it has PIL. The following code gives me an IOError..

```
import Image
a = Image.open("pic.jpg")
a.thumbnail((int(100), int(100)))
```

This is the error I get.

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython console> in <module>()

/sage/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in thumbnail(self, size, resample)
   1520         self.draft(None, size)
   1521 
-> 1522         self.load()
   1523 
   1524         try:

/sage/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.pyc in load(self)
    178 
    179             for d, e, o, a in self.tile:
--> 180                 d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
    181                 seek(o)
    182                 try:

/sage/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in _getdecoder(mode, decoder_name, args, extra)
    373         return apply(decoder, (mode,) + args + extra)
    374     except AttributeError:
--> 375         raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
    376 
    377 def _getencoder(mode, encoder_name, args, extra=()):

IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

It seems, to me, that it can't find libjpeg. I checked MacPorts on my machine, & it looks like the jpeg package has been installed. I also found libjpeg in /opt/local/lib. I tried manipulating LD_LIBRARY_PATH, both in the sage script & while in Sage, using the os library, but haven't been able to get rid of this error. I searched on the Internet for how to get PIL to find libjpeg, but what I found involves modifying setup.py rebuilding PIL. sage doesn't seem to include PIL's setup.py.

Has anyone else encountered this problem & solved it? Perhaps someone familiar w/ PIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to just reinstall PIL.

```
sage.misc.package.install_package("pil", force=True)
```

It was that simple & it just took a minute. Reinstalling it on my machine probably allowed it to find the location of the libraries on my machine.